# Hybrid MVC and Web Site application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I evaluating the MVC framework for my existing application. Trying to write a sample applicaiton where I need to navigate from MVc view to .aspx files and vice versa. The application does seems to be working. Not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

I have set up wild card mapping
I have set up .mvc mapping
I am using IIS6
I am using VS2008 with SP1
I added Controller directory to App_Code
I added Views directory to the web site application

MVC does not seem to be working well with web site application.

I do not know where to activate .mvc ? I do not know where to write the following code

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, False)
                Dim httpHandler As IHttpHandler = New System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler()
                httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current)
                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, False)
```

Can some one help me? I do not know how can I give my code so that you could review that.

Answer (score 1):

This code would go into the Page_Load method in the code behind of the Default.aspx in the root directory.